# Yahoo OAuth 2.0 `bearer_token_not_over_ssl` - explain?

Tags: yahoo-oauth

I'm using the OAuth 2.0 spec for retrieving fantasy football data in the same way this site is using it: http://yfantasysandbox.herokuapp.com/resource/user/game_teams (github repo: https://github.com/whatadewitt/yfsapi)

After retrieving my `access_token` and `refresh_token`, I'm trying retrieve the user teams resource and getting this 401 error for no apparent reason 

`{
  "lang": "en-US",
  "description": "Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=\"bearer_token_not_over_ssl\", realm=\"yahooapis.com\""
}`

It had been working for a few days and it all stopped working suddenly without me having changed anything.  Please let me know if the spec has changed.  I'm using the https protocol for each of my API requests and am sure to get new access_tokens if needed.  My callbackUrl is also using https if that helps.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  Worked fine yesterday.  Today getting "u'Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="bearer_token_not_over_ssl", realm="yahooapis.com"'.  I cannot find anything here: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/errors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working perfectly now.  Looks like it was a disruption in service with the API and not anything fundamental.  Good luck this season!

Comment: yep. you too buddy.  would love if they would give us some descriptor that made it obvious that it was a service disruption.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible explanation is that the urls you are passing are `http`, not `https`.  I was getting this issue, too, until I updated all of my requests to use `https`.